# Shouldn't NSMutableArray retain added objects?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, gnustep

Hi I am facing an issue with Linux / GNUstep. My NSMutableArray(s) do not seem to retain any added objects to them. Shouldn't they? Example:

```
NSString * str = @"test";
NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"before add retainCount: %d", [str retainCount]);
[arr addObject: str];
NSLog(@"after add retainCount: %d", [str retainCount]);
```

Output:

```
before add retainCount: 1
after add retainCount: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(First: You should never rely on `-retainCount`.)

Under the hood, constant strings (strings defined as, e.g., `@"foo"`) are special in that `-retain` and `-release` don't actually do anything; they're always around with a retain count of 1 as an optimization.

If you do something like:

```
NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"foo", @"bar"];
```

You may see what you expect.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with [NSString initWithString: @"test"] and worked.